# What scenarios are enabled by scripting or automating an IM client?

Tags: scripting, instant-messaging

What can I do with an API for an IM client? 
Why do I want this?  What new scenarios are opened up? 
How can I take advantage of it? 
Is it something I can graft into existing apps?
or are IM APIs primarily targeted at enabling new types of applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that I see where an API could be useful for an IM client.

1. A protocol API, which would let you add your own IM protocols to the application.
2. Chat API, which lets you add things such as spell checking, expanding text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Kik API, you can implement features that are intentionally left out of core client for UX simplicity reasons. For example, a lot of users demand video or location sharing features. These are the most obvious ones. Kik API is available on Android and Iphone platforms and takes only about 15 minutes to integrate into your mobile app. You can get more info on API website or blog: http://www.kik.com/dev and http://apiblog.kik.com

Disclaimer: I'm on of the developers behind Kik API :)